# iPad keeps disconnecting from ad-hoc networks

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

I have a computer with Internet connection via Ethernet, it is Wi-fi capable so in order to share the Internet connection I had set up an ad-hoc network.

It works fine with other computers, but if only my iPad is connected, the link breaks whenever mi iPad is sleeping.

When turning on my iPad, I have to reset the ad-hoc network in the computer in order to have Internet available in my iPad again.

I wonder why it happens. Thanks.

Comment: so your iPad is the server ? try setting new ad-hoc (Internet Sharing) without iPad active.

Comment: @Buscar웃 no. The computer is the server.

Answer (score 1):

i'm having the same problem, i use my laptop as internet server, all other computer is connected to the network and have internet access, when i use my tablet and after a while it losses the internet access even though it's still connected to the network (only skype keeps working, no browsing and no facebook).

to fix it you need to do the following:

right click on Computer >> **Properties** >> Device Manager >> network adapters >> right click on Ethernet Controller >> Properties >> Power Management >> uncheck the box "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

it should work fine now

Comment: It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I use the set up on my computer for "Internet sharing".

That should work for you.

For that I enable the "Bluetooth pan" to act as the transmitter.

Then just enable Internet sharing and it is done.

[image]

In your specific case:
"Connected via Ethernet cable and using your wifi card as transmitter"
Turn off iPad and set up the adhoc
Turn on iPad.

For some reason your ipad is acting as server ? To know more need more information about your set up.

Comment: No. My iPad is not the server. The computer is the server and it runs Ubuntu. I did set the ad-hoc network with the iPad turned off. I've tried before with computer running Windows and it had the same behavior.

Comment: It certainly acts as server! I do not know why, but it takes over the ad-hoc and redistributes it ? That would explain the behavior. You could check to see who is connected to your computer vs who is connected to ipad.